# Can you Profile Ms test integration tests?

Tags: mstest, integration-testing, profiling

I have never done any profiling, and have come across the first place that I really want to do it.

Is it possible to profile my MS integration tests? What tools do I need? is there something built-in to VS 2008 professional?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer to your question, but no, there is nothing built into VS 2008 Professional that will let you do profiling.  There are profiling tools in VS 2008 Team Suite edition, but not in Professional.  I'm not sure if you can profile MS Unit tests with it (only ever used it for a running application).